# Are wildcards allowed in the Log4j (via Spring Boot Logging) logging.level property?

Tags: java, logging

While I was installing a Java application that uses Log4j (via Spring Boot Logging), I was told that I could configure the logging level for all packages used in the application by including the following line in the `application.properties` file:

`logging.level.*=ERROR`

Where `ERROR` could be whatever logging level I wanted to use.

However, as I changed the level from one value to another, no matter what value I used, I found that log messages down to `DEBUG` would appear in the log.

Eventually, I found that using specific package names I could control the minimum level to be logged.  That is, `logging.level.org.orgname.appname=ERROR` would do what I wanted.

Are the log level properties meant to to support wildcards like "*"?

Comment: *"Are the log level properties meant to to support wildcards like "*"?"* - Short answer: No.

Comment: Thanks for the…ermm…thoughtful…reply,@Andreas.⑴I read docs thoroughly.⑵Colleague vowed that `logging.level.*` is valid and works, despite my experience.⑶Have you tried using search engines to find "logging.level.*"? It's nearly impossible. I finally found it as a syntax example in some documentation, but Google, etc. won't find it.∴People who answer "RTFM" are unpleasant.

Comment: Editing my question because it turns out to be Spring Boot logging using Log4j internally.  However, the result is the same, as @StephenC wrote.

Answer (score 9):

Since my question seems unpopular, but I've found an answer anyway, I'll post it for completeness.

Neither Log4j nor Spring Boot Logging support wildcards such as `logging.level.*`.  There is some documentation that uses that exact phrase, but they mean for the reader to substitute a package name for the asterisk.  My colleagues didn't understand that and used it verbatim in documentation for their application.

The equivalent in Spring Boot Logging is `logging.level.root`.  The equivalent in Log4j configuration files is `log4j.rootLogger`, although that requires one or more additional arguments giving the names of log appender objects.